# When the RestApi has ResponseEntity<void> of spring has return value it returns ClientProtocolException

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a RestApi exposed which on case returns status ok back to client.
The method signature of the method is `ResponseEntity<void> methodName(){}`.
This method is a deleteApi.

In the return `responseEntity` is created with just `Status OK` and no body or any other header details are appended.

Seen in the logs that I get `ClientProtocolException` when the call is made , saw that when the same is executed through the REST client (postman) received correct `Status OK` message in the response.

- What are the reasons when the `ClientProtocolException` is raised?
- If the return type is `ResponeEntity<Void>` is it mandatory to send body with it ?
- How do i avoid getting the above exception?

Code:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> methodName()
{
   // your business logic 
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try as below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> methodName() { 
    // your business logic 
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```